# Android: touch items behind navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer *(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)* and a button in my layout.

When the drawer is opened, I can't directly touch the button (because it's in the layout behind the drawer). I have to click somewhere else, the drawer will close (which is normal) and I can click the button.

What I want is, **when the drawer is open, I want the button behind is still clickable without closing the drawer**.

==

This is my layout (classic drawer layout)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...>

        <FrameLayout...>
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout...
                    <Button /> ---> here is my button
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" /> --> here is my drawer

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: can explain me some more detail ?

Comment: @Mohammad Ali I posted the layout

Comment: mins u wan to a when u click on button then drawer open when u click on again on button then drawer close ??

Comment: @Mohammad Ali No, the default behaviour is, when the drawer is open and you want to click the button behind, the drawer will close. I want to click the button behind without closing the drawer.

Comment: u min open drawer time u want to click drawer behind button like without closing drawer ?

Comment: @Mohammad Ali i have a layout, there is a button, the drawer is close. I swipe, now the drawer is open. i want to click the button behind without closing the drawer which is open.

Answer (score 1):

Override Navigation Drawer  or try sliding pane layout

Comment: how can I make the items behind the drawer + in the drawer clickable at the same time ?

Comment: you need to extend from drawer layout new class and override method onTouchEvent, if u "ctrl+click" on DrawerLayout on your IDE it opens to you source code of this view.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what I want

Comment: you will make your own drawer with your custom rules, that when you click not in drawer panel it will not close